# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object one to many realtionship

Tags: laravel

My model:

**Admin.php**

```php
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

at my controller:

**LoginController.php**

```php
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    foreach($this->guard()->user()->role as $role)
    {
        if($role->name=='SuperAdmin')
        {
            return redirect(route('super.admin.index'));
        }
        elseif ($role->name == 'Admin')
        {
            return redirect(route('super.admin.index'));
        }
    }
}
```

on my SuperAdmin middeware:

```php
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $role=Auth::user()->role;
    if (is_null($role)) {
        return redirect(route('/'));
    }

  if($role->name=='SuperAdmin')
  {
      return $next($request);
  }
  return redirect('/');

}
```

}

I have created a custom guard named: `Admin` and custom login sytem. I have used one-to-many relationship, but it's giving me:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Just quick comment, stuff like this should be extracted to something else, like middleware.

Comment: yes i know! i was just trying this out! thank you anyway

Comment: Meh, if its just one-time.. I did that xxx times, and it took place in my daily routine.

Comment: i am not going to make the same mistake. thank for your tips xd :P

Answer (score 0):

Your `role` relation is `belomgsTo`. For that case `$this->guard()->user()->role`
return instance of `Role` object or null.

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    $role = $this->guard()->user()->role;
    if (is_null($role)) {
       return redirect(route('super.admin.index')); 
    }    

    if($role->name=='SuperAdmin') {
        return redirect(route('super.admin.index'));
    } elseif ($role->name == 'Admin') {
        return redirect(route('super.admin.index'));
    }
}
```

In middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (is_null(Auth::user())) {
        return redirect(route('/'));
    }

    $role=Auth::user()->role;
    if (is_null($role)) {
        return redirect(route('/'));
    }

  if($role->name=='SuperAdmin')
  {
      return $next($request);
  }
  return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: What about @JubayerAhmed?

Comment: public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $role=Auth::user()->role;

      if($role->name=='SuperAdmin')
      {
          return $next($request);
      }
      return redirect('/');

    }   that's my middleware everything is same as before i am using middleware now. but it;s giving me trying to get property 'role' of non-object

Comment: you must be check $role is null

Comment: in my database my role is not null. still i have to check?

Comment: For all case you must be check

Comment: I have checked it. still it's giving me the same error.you can check my post i edited it and added the middleware function.

Comment: Trying to get property 'role' of non-object . this error

Comment: I think `$this->guard()->user()` return null. Check that part

Comment: my gaurd is okay! i ahve checked it. can you please check my post again in middleware the problem. do i have to declare somewhere at the middleware which gaurd i am using? why is this giving me this role error.

Comment: if (is_null(Auth::user())) {
        return redirect(route('/'));
    }

Comment: if (is_null(Auth::user())) {
        return redirect(route('/'));
    }   it's a null but i don't want it to be null. i have a gaurd name admin. the model of that gaurd Admin .and in admin i have my role function which is one to one. but it's showing nul as if i don't have any gaurd. giving me the non object error